# How to get a list of shared libraries used in the pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries

I can get all the libraries in Jenkins like this:
    Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptor("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries").getLibraries()

but it gives me all the libraries even if they are not used in the current project. I can see in the console log that only one of those libraries was loaded. How to get it's name?

Loading library **name_of_the_library**

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer you were expecting but a simple solution would be to make a variable with the name of your library/ies and println it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def libs = inst.getDescriptor("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries").getLibraries()

for( lib in libs ) {
        def lib_path = lib.getRetriever().getScm().getRemote()
}
```

But this gives me all the libraries, not only shared ones